# How to sort an object Array using a custom Comparator interface in Java 8?

Tags: java, sorting, interface, java-8, comparator

Custom implementation of Comparator

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Comparator<T>  {

int compare(T t1, T t2);

static <T> Comparator<T> comparing(
        Function<T, Comparable> f){
    return (p1, p2) -> f.apply(p1).compareTo(f.apply(p2));
}

default Comparator<T> thenComparing(
        Comparator<T> cmp){
            return (p1, p2) ->
                    this.compare(p1, p2) == 0 ?
                            cmp.compare(p1, p2) : this.compare(p1, p2);
}

default Comparator<T> thenComparing(
        Function<T, Comparable> f){
            Comparator<T> cmp = comparing(f);
    return thenComparing(cmp);
  }
}
```

I have created a Person class with three fields, namely the firstName, lastName and age, and their respective getters and setters. Using the custom Comparator class I want to sort an array of persons in main as under:

```
    Comparator<Person> cmp = Comparator
            .comparing(Person::getLastName) // Extract Property and compare
            .thenComparing(Person::getFirstName)
            .thenComparing(Person::getAge);

     Person arr[] = new Person[]{
        new Person("Sean", "Gilmore", 22),
                new Person("Aaron", "Reidy", 21),
                new Person("Jane", "Kennedy", 53),
                new Person("Mike", "English", 49)
    };


    Arrays.sort(arr, cmp);
```

However `Arrays.sort(arr, cmp);` throws a compile error `no instance of type variable T exists so that Comparator<Person> conforms to Comparator<? super T>`

I'm thrown off by this error and I would like to know how to sort the Person array using `cmp` Comparator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily adapt your `Comparator` to the JDK's like this:

```
Arrays.sort(arr, cmp::compare);
```

I believe Guava recommended a similar pattern to adapt their functional interfaces before they were retrofitted for Java 8.

Comment: @shmosei `cmp:compare` would still give you a `java.util.Comparator`. There are other options too but you eventually can't pass anything but a `java.util.Comparator` to the method in question so the answer still remains : you can't do it.

Comment: @CKing I didn't interpret the question as trying to avoid the JDK's `Comparator` entirely. I think OP is just asking how his custom interface can be used with the built-in sort functionality.

Comment: @shmosei I fell for the same argument in my head but then I read this line from the question *I'm thrown off my this error and I would like to know how to sort the Person array using cmp Comparator* which convinced me that the OP clearly needed an explanation for why it can't be done rather than how to do it. (The OP was thrown away that he can't pass a `Comparator` to a method that takes a `Comparator`). This can be further inferred from the comment on my answer from the OP saying *So that means I'll have to implement sort to use my custom Comparator?* The OP is exploring *Java* in general!

Comment: @CKing I hear you, but I suspect you're putting more thought into OP's words than he did :)

Comment: @CKing That's one statement I fully agree with.

Comment: @shmosel thanks a lot for that! works like a charm! @CKing I wanted to know why it isn't working and how should I fix the compile time error. I have a follow up question, how is this solution able to override the cmp compare method? The method signature of Arrays.sort is `public static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)` but I believe `cmp::compare` is a lambda (Method Reference Syntax). Could you please shed some light on this? Thanks :)

Comment: @etSingh `cmp::compare` is a method reference which translates to `(a, b) -> cmp.compare(a, b)`. In other words, you're creating a JDK `Comparator` that delegates to your custom `Comparator`, similar to the facade mentioned in the [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42208213/how-to-sort-an-object-array-using-a-custom-comparator-interface-in-java-8/42210897#comment71578845_42208707) to @CKing's answer.

Answer (score 3):

The fully qualified name of a `class` in *Java* includes it's package name.

The [Arrays.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator)) method expects a `java.util.Comparator` implementation. Your custom `Comparator` is not the same is `java.util.Comparator`.

The `sort` method in `Arrays` class is a `static` method so you can't extend `Arrays` and override this method. If you want to use [Arrays.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator)), use an implementation of `java.util.Comparator`. There is no way around it.

Comment: So that means I'll have to implement sort to use my custom Comparator?

Comment: @HarpreetSingh Or you write a facade for your custom `Comparator` class. Anyway, why don't you use the genuine `Comparator`?

Comment: @Flown That *Facade* is still a *java.util.Comparator*.

Comment: @CKing This is what I've meant.

Comment: Why are you reinventing wheels?

Comment: @ncmathsadist just playing around with Java 8 really